# Values disappearing after refresh

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Once I log in I set username and loggedIn value, I import the values to my component, it works but after refreshing the page this goes back to original value, why is this happening?

I didn't have this issue when Using vuex in vue 2. Do I really have to store this data in localStorage? Wtf.

```js
const loggedIn = ref(false);
const userName = ref('');

export default function useAuth() {

 const login = async ({ email, password }) => {
    try {
      const result = await AuthService.login({ email: email, password: password });
      userName.value = result.data.nick;
      loggedIn.value = true;
    }
   }
return {login, loggedIn, userName}
}
```

Comment: Yes, it would help if you use `localStorage` for something like this. If you want not to store the user data in `localStorage` you have to ask them to log in every time they refresh the page. Also, using data for putting `loggedIn` and `userName` is so much better.

Comment: Hey when you refreshing the page that time state will always Clear.You need to use Session Storage/Local Storage.

Comment: Also, you are missing `catch` or `finally` expression. At least one of them is required. The code is invalid.

Comment: There is no way you could have achieved that in vue 2 in native way, you probably were using a library such vuex-persist. The vuex state is ALWAYS cleared on page refresh. The only way to keep your state after refreshing the page is by using localStorage or sessionStorage (which gets deleted when the browser is closed)

Answer (score 1):

A browser does not automatically store the current memory of a JavaScript application. On a page refresh, the complete page is re-rendered and a new "application" is loaded. You can influence this behavior when you store your state on the back-end site (push relevant data to back-end via API and store it there e.g. in a database) or you can store your state in the browser's storage. This can be as a cookie, session/local storage and IndexedDB. Depending on your needs, you can then retrieve the relevant state from the back-end or your locally stored data on page load. If you are using Vuex, there are plugins which allow you to do this automatically. You can still use Vuex with Vue3 (use `useStore()` instead of `this.$store`).

If you are using just the plain composition API, the in-memory variables won't be saved. You can, however, easily watch the variables and set the values to the local store by yourself. See e.g. [this example](https://gist.github.com/ChaDonSom/a61d2d592e06c90be23b77f257c587d2) where a new variable is created with the value from the local storage (on page load), a watcher is defined where the value is going to be set to the storage and then finally the variable is returned from this module.

Comment: I am also facing this issue when I fetch data and store it in an array, whenever I change tabs its loading, but whenever I refresh the page it dissapears, why is this happening? I tried `onMounted`, `onBeforeMount` aswell..

Comment: You are loading the data from the API in your in-memory JavaScript array which is only available until the page is refreshed. A refresh completely wipes the memory. This is how browsers work. You can only circumvent this, if you additionally store it in local storage or somewhere locally and then load it from there again on page load. Or you fetch it everytime again from the API. Usually, you would fetch most data always from the API and only store locally some preferences (like selected language or an auth token, which is usually in a cookie).